# How to make Keras compute a certain metric on validation data only?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using `tf.keras` with TensorFlow 1.14.0. I have implemented a custom metric that is quite computationally intensive and it slows down the training process if I simply add it to the list of metrics provided as `model.compile(..., metrics=[...])`.

How do I make Keras skip computation of the metric during training iterations but compute it on validation data (and print it) at the end of each epoch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564427/10375049

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this you can create a tf.Variable in the metric calculation that determines if the calculation goes ahead and then updates it when a test is run using a callback. e.g.

```py
class MyCustomMetric(tf.keras.metrics.Metrics):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Initialise as normal and add flag variable for when to run computation
        super(MyCustomMetric, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.metric_variable = self.add_weight(name='metric_variable', initializer='zeros')
        self.on = tf.Variable(False)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        # Use conditional to determine if computation is done
        if self.on:
            # run computation
            self.metric_variable.assign_add(computation_result)

    def result(self):
        return self.metric_variable

    def reset_states(self):
        self.metric_variable.assign(0.)

class ToggleMetrics(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    '''On test begin (i.e. when evaluate() is called or 
     validation data is run during fit()) toggle metric flag '''
    def on_test_begin(self, logs):
        for metric in self.model.metrics:
            if 'MyCustomMetric' in metric.name:
                metric.on.assign(True)
    def on_test_end(self,  logs):
        for metric in self.model.metrics:
            if 'MyCustomMetric' in metric.name:
                metric.on.assign(False)
```

Comment: So it's possible to run the entire model to acquire a metric inside the `update_state` method? How does the metric get access to the model to use? Do we just have to pass it as an extra `__init__` parameter?

Comment: The update_state method receives the model output through the y_pred variable.

Comment: Do you mean `metric.update_metric` by `metric.on`? Or is it a built-in attribute of `tf.keras.metrics.Metrics`?

Comment: How does this solution take care of the cases where evaluation is done in batches?

Comment: Have you ever tried to run this piece of code? What is 'metric.on'?