# How to prevent Keras from computing metrics during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Tensorflow/Keras 2.4.1 and I have a (unsupervised) custom metric that takes several of my model inputs as parameters such as:

```py
model = build_model() # returns a tf.keras.Model object
my_metric = custom_metric(model.output, model.input[0], model.input[1])
model.add_metric(my_metric)
[...]
model.fit([...]) # training with fit
```

However, it happens that `custom_metric` is very expensive so I would like it to be computed during validation only. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60829012/6315123) but I hardly understand how I can adapt the solution to my metric that uses several model inputs as parameter since the `update_state` method doesn't seem flexible.

In my context, is there a way to avoid computing my metric during training, aside from writing my own training loop ?
Also, I am very surprised we cannot natively specify to Tensorflow that some metrics should only be computed at validation time, is there a reason for that ?

In addition, since the model is trained to optimize the loss, and that the training dataset should not be used to evaluate a model, I don't even understand why, by default, Tensorflow computes metrics during training.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the simplest solution to compute a metric only on the validation is using a custom callback.

here we define our dummy callback:

```
class MyCustomMetricCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, train=None, validation=None):
        super(MyCustomMetricCallback, self).__init__()
        self.train = train
        self.validation = validation

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):

        mse = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error

        if self.train:
            logs['my_metric_train'] = float('inf')
            X_train, y_train = self.train[0], self.train[1]
            y_pred = self.model.predict(X_train)
            score = mse(y_train, y_pred)
            logs['my_metric_train'] = np.round(score, 5)

        if self.validation:
            logs['my_metric_val'] = float('inf')
            X_valid, y_valid = self.validation[0], self.validation[1]
            y_pred = self.model.predict(X_valid)
            val_score = mse(y_pred, y_valid)
            logs['my_metric_val'] = np.round(val_score, 5)
```

Given this dummy model:

```
def build_model():

  inp1 = Input((5,))
  inp2 = Input((5,))
  out = Concatenate()([inp1, inp2])
  out = Dense(1)(out)

  model = Model([inp1, inp2], out)
  model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

  return model
```

and this data:

```
X_train1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,5))
X_train2 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,5))
y_train = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,1))

X_val1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,5))
X_val2 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,5))
y_val = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,1))
```

you can use the custom callback to compute the metric both on train and validation:

```
model = build_model()

model.fit([X_train1, X_train2], y_train, epochs=10, 
          callbacks=[MyCustomMetricCallback(train=([X_train1, X_train2],y_train), validation=([X_val1, X_val2],y_val))])
```

only on validation:

```
model = build_model()

model.fit([X_train1, X_train2], y_train, epochs=10, 
          callbacks=[MyCustomMetricCallback(validation=([X_val1, X_val2],y_val))])
```

only on train:

```
model = build_model()

model.fit([X_train1, X_train2], y_train, epochs=10, 
          callbacks=[MyCustomMetricCallback(train=([X_train1, X_train2],y_train))])
```

remember only that **the callback evaluates the metrics one-shot** on the data, like any metric/loss computed by default by keras on the `validation_data`.

[here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZT9jDHxTQLWzc8rMJ5dfgUT77Rr3j-GI?usp=sharing) is the running code.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use `learning_phase` but only in symbolic tensor mode (graph) mode:

So, at first we need to disable eager mode (this must be done right after importing tensorflow):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Then you can create your metric using a symbolic if (`backend.switch`):

```
def metric_graph(in1, in2, out):
    actual_metric = out * (in1 + in2)
    return K.switch(K.learning_phase(), tf.zeros((1,)), actual_metric)
```

The method `add_metric` will ask for a name and an aggregation method, which you can set to `"mean"`.

So, here is one example:

```
x1 = numpy.ones((5,3))
x2 = numpy.ones((5,3))
y = 3*numpy.ones((5,1))

vx1 = numpy.ones((5,3))
vx2 = numpy.ones((5,3))
vy = 3*numpy.ones((5,1))

def metric_eager(in1, in2, out):
    if (K.learning_phase()):
        return 0
    else:
        return out * (in1 + in2)

def metric_graph(in1, in2, out):
    actual_metric = out * (in1 + in2)
    return K.switch(K.learning_phase(), tf.zeros((1,)), actual_metric) 

ins1 = Input((3,))
ins2 = Input((3,))
outs = Concatenate()([ins1, ins2])
outs = Dense(1)(outs)
model = Model([ins1, ins2],outs)
model.add_metric(metric_graph(ins1, ins2, outs), name='my_metric', aggregation='mean')
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit([x1, x2],y, validation_data=([vx1, vx2], vy), epochs=3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I can't disable the eager execution as some of my loss components require indexing on the model's output, which is not possible on symbolic tensors. I know eager execution should be avoided when training as it creates performances issues, but I didn't figured out an other solution for my project (and this would be an other thread.)

Comment: Thank you for this solution, in TF 2.10 I have to slightly adapt it by:

`K.switch(tf.convert_to_tensor(K.learning_phase() == 1, dtype=bool), tf.convert_to_tensor(0.0, dtype=tf.float64), actual_metric)`

Note, that I used `tf.float64` since actual_metric's return type was `tf.float64` in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Since the metrics are being run within the `train_step` function of `keras.Model`, filtering out train disabled metrics without altering the API requires to subclass `keras.Model`.

We define a simple metric wrapper:

```py
class TrainDisabledMetric(Metric):

  def __init__(self, metric: Metric):
    super().__init__(name=metric.name)
    self._metric = metric

  def update_state(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self._metric.update_state(*args, **kwargs)

  def reset_state(self):
    return self._metric.reset_state()

  def result(self):
    return self._metric.result()
```

and subclass `keras.Model` to filter out those metrics during train:

```py
class CustomModel(keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def compile(self, optimizer='rmsprop', loss=None, metrics=None,
              loss_weights=None, weighted_metrics=None, run_eagerly=None,
              steps_per_execution=None, jit_compile=None, **kwargs):

    from_serialized = kwargs.get('from_serialized', False)

    super().compile(optimizer, loss, metrics=metrics, loss_weights=loss_weights,
                    weighted_metrics=weighted_metrics, run_eagerly=run_eagerly,
                    steps_per_execution=steps_per_execution,
                    jit_compile=jit_compile, **kwargs)

    self.on_train_compiled_metrics = self.compiled_metrics

    if metrics is not None:

      def get_on_train_traverse_tree(structure):
        flat = tf.nest.flatten(structure)
        on_train = [not isinstance(e, TrainDisabledMetric) for e in flat]
        full_tree = tf.nest.pack_sequence_as(structure, on_train)
        return get_traverse_shallow_structure(lambda s: any(tf.nest.flatten(s)),
                                              full_tree)

      on_train_sub_tree = get_on_train_traverse_tree(metrics)
      flat_on_train = flatten_up_to(on_train_sub_tree, metrics)

      def clean_tree(tree):
        if isinstance(tree, list):
          _list = []
          for t in tree:
            r = clean_tree(t)
            if r:
              _list.append(r)
          return _list

        elif isinstance(tree, dict):
          _tree = {}
          for k, v in tree.items():
            r = clean_tree(v)
            if r:
              _tree[k] = r
          return _tree
        else:
          return tree

      pruned_on_train_sub_tree = clean_tree(on_train_sub_tree)
      pruned_flat_on_train = [m for keep, m in
                              zip(tf.nest.flatten(on_train_sub_tree),
                                  flat_on_train) if keep]

      on_train_metrics = tf.nest.pack_sequence_as(pruned_on_train_sub_tree,
                                                  pruned_flat_on_train)

      self.on_train_compiled_metrics = compile_utils.MetricsContainer(
        on_train_metrics, weighted_metrics=None, output_names=self.output_names,
        from_serialized=from_serialized)

  def train_step(self, data):
    x, y, sample_weight = data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(data)
    # Run forward pass.
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    self._validate_target_and_loss(y, loss)
    # Run backwards pass.
    self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight, training=True)

  def compute_metrics(self, x, y, y_pred, sample_weight, training=False):
    del x  # The default implementation does not use `x`.

    if training:
      self.on_train_compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
      metrics = self.on_train_metrics
    else:
      self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
      metrics = self.metrics
    # Collect metrics to return
    return_metrics = {}
    for metric in metrics:
      result = metric.result()
      if isinstance(result, dict):
        return_metrics.update(result)
      else:
        return_metrics[metric.name] = result
    return return_metrics

  @property
  def on_train_metrics(self):
    metrics = []
    if self._is_compiled:
      # TODO(omalleyt): Track `LossesContainer` and `MetricsContainer` objects
      # so that attr names are not load-bearing.
      if self.compiled_loss is not None:
        metrics += self.compiled_loss.metrics
      if self.on_train_compiled_metrics is not None:
        metrics += self.on_train_compiled_metrics.metrics

    for l in self._flatten_layers():
      metrics.extend(l._metrics)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    return metrics
```

Now given a keras model, we can wrap it and compile it with train disabled metrics:

```py
model: keras.Model = ...
custom_model = CustomModel(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.output)

train_enabled_metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]

# wrap train disabled metrics with `TrainDisabledMetric`:
train_disabled_metrics = [
  TrainDisabledMetric(tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())]

metrics = train_enabled_metrics + train_disabled_metrics

custom_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
                     loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
                       from_logits=True), metrics=metrics, )

custom_model.fit(ds_train, epochs=6, validation_data=ds_test, )
```

The metric `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` is computed only during validation:

```
Epoch 1/6
469/469 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3522 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8366 - val_loss: 0.1978 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9086 - val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 1.3197
Epoch 2/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1631 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9526 - val_loss: 0.1429 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9587 - val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 1.1910
Epoch 3/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1178 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9654 - val_loss: 0.1139 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9661 - val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 1.1369
Epoch 4/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0909 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9735 - val_loss: 0.0981 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9715 - val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 1.0434
Epoch 5/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0735 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9784 - val_loss: 0.0913 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9721 - val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 0.9862
Epoch 6/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0606 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9823 - val_loss: 0.0824 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9761 - val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 1.0024
```